# How can I store information about the 50 US states in Android / Java?

Tags: java, android

I am making my own Android application and don't know if there's a categorically proper way of assembling something like this.

I am making an app that has info on all 50 US states. If I were to organize my data in SQL, I'd use a table. Each row would have many columns: State Name, Year Founded, Capitol Name, etc.

However, now that I am building an app in Android / Java, I don't know what the correct way is to organize this kind of data.

Comment: SQLite is your friend.

Comment: You can use SQL databases in Android / Python / Java.

Comment: Oh, wow, I had no idea. Are there any good tutorials you might recommend for this?

Comment: Asking "How do I make a table in Java?" is like asking "How do I make a hash-table in SQL?" - neither are the best solution for the problem.

Comment: @immibis To be fair, I am asking for the best solution for this problem.

Comment: In that case, why not ask "How can I store information about the 50 US states in Java?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the columns are known and discrete, you should create a model class to to hold all information for a State.  You can then have a `List` of those states.

For example:

Your model class

```
public class State {

    private String name;
    private String yearFounded;
    private String capitalName;

    public State(String name, String yearFounded, String capitalName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.yearFounded = yearFounded;
        this.capitalName = capitalName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getYearFounded() {
        return yearFounded;
    }

    public void setYearFounded(String yearFounded) {
        this.yearFounded = yearFounded;
    }

    public String getCapitalName() {
        return capitalName;
    }

    public void setCapitalName(String capitalName) {
        this.capitalName = capitalName;
    }
}
```

And when using it:

```
List<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();
states.add(new State("Alabama", "1819", "Montgomery"));
```

Comment: Is this easier / preferable than using an SQLite database?

Comment: This would likely be in addition to using a SQLite database.  SQLite databases are normally used when information that may change needs to be stored across application instances.  If this is really for the 50 states, it is easy enough to hard-code all 50 states and their information in the manner shown in my answer.

Comment: For future knowledge, say there were 100,000 states. Then I could invoke SQLite, iterate over all rows, call states.add for each one, and have a final list that has everything?